# Electromagnetic plane waves

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I have a question, a planewave impedance E/H =377 ohm, and it is said that for plane waves none of the components electric and magnetic dominates they are indistinguishable or same. But what about this wave impedance relation E/H =377
which can be written as, E=377 X H, which tells that Electric field strength is 377 times more than magnetic at this wave impedance.
So my confusion is what variable or quantity we are talkin about when we say for plane wave none of the component dominate. Or like in near field when electric or magnetic component dominate. Like looking into plane wave impedance relation E=377 X H, I cannot grasp the idea that if electric field strength is 377 times H  and still we say both components behave same way no one dominates. As far as behavior (oscillations or E & H complement each other) concerned it stays throughout.   It is also true that I cannot compare two different quantities numerically, but then my other question would be how we can tell through some measurement in different regions of an antenna , that which component dominates where?

Comment: is 732 kilograms more or less than 7 seconds?

Comment: Correct, but are E & H as far apart as Kg and Seconds, We can tell through some experiment which component dominate where, so my question is basically about such  measurement, how can we differentiate about dominance of these components through some experiment or mathematics.

Comment: The Photon is right - E and H really are as different as kilograms and seconds, and definitely so in SI units. You simply **cannot** drop the $\Omega$ in $E=(376.7\:\Omega)H$, it's like saying $x= vt=(30\:\mathrm{m/s})t=30t$.

Answer (score 1):

```
 a planewave impedance E/H =377 ohm, and it is said that for plane waves none 
 of the components electric and magnetic dominates they are indistinguishable 
 or same.
```

The electric and the magnetic fields do behave in the same way in an electromagnetic wave, and a combination of both is needed for the wave to propagate and both are equally important for the wave to exist. However what you are suggesting is that the value of the electric and the magnetic fields are the same which is not true. The values may be different and for any wave $E = cB$, where $c$ is the speed of light and that is forever fixed. Using $B = \mu_0 H$, you get the above relation which you stated.

```
 E=377 X H, which tells that Electric field strength is 377 times more than 
 magnetic at this wave impedance. although it looks some thing is wrong with 
 way of looking because it tells same field strength without any distance 
 dependence, so whats wrong at this way of looking?"
```

I hope this part too is clarified by the above comment made.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So what is then that variable which "dominates" is used for if not the field strength. Because in literature we see this word to describe the behavior of EM waves in different region?

Comment: what it probably means is that the electric and magnetic fields are having an equal physical contribution in the propagation of a wave and it doesn't mean that their numerical values are the same... i hope that is clear now...

Comment: If you want to make this a valid answer you need to discuss the units used to express the impedance of free space.